# Can we design custom notification similar to in Android Nougat style notifications?

Tags: android, push-notification

I have an app which does most of the work using notifications. I wanted to improve the layout of my notification like those in Android Nougat.

Even using a custom layout for notifications doesn't change the appearance on older Android versions.

Is there any way to create such custom nougat like notifications?

Comment: I thought that might solve your issue, but since it didn't, I've re-opened the question. (gave you a upvote as well)

Answer (score 1):

The [`NotificationCompat`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat.Builder.html) class features is a maximum what you can to achieve.

Most of Android OS version has their own notificaion types.
That's why in old version it is impossible..